# public key issue on installing google-cloud-sdk on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, public-key, google-cloud-sdk

I'm installing **google-cloud-sdk** on an AWS ec2.
As first step I'd updated YUM with Cloud SDK repo information as reported on [GCP official doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#rpm). But when I try to install gcp sdk by:

`sudo yum install google-cloud-sdk`

i got:

`Public key for ******************-google-cloud-sdk-316.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm is not installed`

And I don't understand how to resolve the issue because the wget (from the ec2 machine) of the gpg keys works.
Someone knwos how to resolve it?

My /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo:

```
[google-cloud-sdk]
name=Google Cloud SDK
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

Comment: Hello, just to confirm, is the complete message you are getting? Are you using the latest version of Cloud SDK?

Comment: Hi Harif,
as You can see I'm using the version 316, infact:

Your current Cloud SDK version is: 316.0.0
The latest available version is: 316.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Is always recommended use the latest version of [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#installing_the_latest_version), also, about the error message you are getting usually could be mitigated on two ways:

1. Disable the rpm signature check in YUM repo config
2. Import the public keys on server

Regarding to the point 2, you can import the key pair as is recommended in the official [Ec2 documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/import-key-pair.html).

Comment: Hi Harif,
I made the download of 2 gpg file,  
"aws ec2 import-key-pair" don't like the gpg files, so i tryed "gpg --import", and now the gpg  keys are in the machine:
[ec2-user@ip-******* gcp-sdk-conf]$ gpg --list-keys
/home/ec2-user/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
---------------------------------
pub   2048R/BA07F4FB 2018-04-01 [expires: 2021-03-31]
uid                  Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com>

pub   2048R/3E1BA8D5 2015-06-24
uid                  Google Cloud Packages RPM Signing Key <gc-team@google.com>

but error remains: .... key ID 3e1ba8d5: NOKEY

Comment: can you tell me the content of this file? /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo

Comment: Hi Harif I updated my question with the content of /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo